# ASPX connection with c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to create a Dynamic QRcode generator with c# and aspx i don't know html much and i get some error while i try to run it on my browser(opera)

**This is my c# code  QCCode.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using ZXing;


namespace QRCodeSample
{
    public partial class QCCode : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        // Event to generate the QC Code
        protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GenerateMyQCCode(txtQCCode.Text);
        }
        protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReadQRCode();
        }
        private void GenerateMyQCCode(string QCText)
        {
            var QCwriter = new BarcodeWriter();
            QCwriter.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
            var result = QCwriter.Write(QCText);
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/images/MyQRImage.jpg");
            var barcodeBitmap = new Bitmap(result);

            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,
                   FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    barcodeBitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
            imgageQRCode.Visible = true;
            imgageQRCode.ImageUrl = "~/images/MyQRImage.jpg";

        }

        private void ReadQRCode()
        {
            var QCreader = new BarcodeReader();
            string QCfilename = Path.Combine(Request.MapPath
               ("~/images"), "MyQRImage.jpg");
            var QCresult = QCreader.Decode(new Bitmap(QCfilename));
            if (QCresult != null)
            {
                lblQRCode.Text = "My QR Code: " + QCresult.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my html QCCode.aspx**

```
"<%@ Page Language = "C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
   CodeBehind="QCCode.aspx.cs"
   Inherits="QRCodeSample.QCCode" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml%22%3E
   <head runat="server">
      <title>Sample ASP.NET application to Generate and
         Read QR Code from a Browser</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="QCFrom" runat="server">
         <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID = "txtQCCode" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox >
             <asp:Button ID = "btnQCGenerate" runat="server"
               Text="Create My QR Code"
               OnClick="btnQCGenerate_Click" />
            <hr/>
            <asp:Image ID = "imgageQRCode" Width="100px"
               Height="100px" runat="server"
               Visible="false" /> <br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID = "btnQCRead" Text="Read My QR Code"
               runat="server" OnClick="btnQCRead_Click" />
               <br /><br />
            <asp:Label ID = "lblQRCode" runat="server">
            </asp:Label>
         </div>
      </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

**This is the QCCode.aspx.designer.cs page i don't know what is this**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated. 
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace QRCodeSample
{


    public partial class QCCode
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// QCFrom control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm QCFrom;

        /// <summary>
        /// txtQCCode control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtQCCode;

        /// <summary>
        /// btnQCGenerate control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnQCGenerate;

        /// <summary>
        /// imgageQRCode control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgageQRCode;

        /// <summary>
        /// btnQCRead control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnQCRead;

        /// <summary>
        /// lblQRCode control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblQRCode;
    }
}
```

**This is the error i get when i run it**

```
CS1061: 'qccode_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnQCGenerate_Click' and no accessible extension method 'btnQCGenerate_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'qccode_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


Line 13:             <asp:TextBox ID = "txtQCCode" runat="server">
Line 14:             </asp:TextBox >
Line 15:              <asp:Button ID = "btnQCGenerate" runat="server" Text="Create My QR Code" OnClick="btnQCGenerate_Click" />
Line 16:             <hr/>
Line 17:             <asp:Image ID = "imgageQRCode" Width="100px" Height="100px" runat="server" Visible="false" /> <br /><br />

C:\Users\bugra\source\repos\QrCode\QCCode.aspx(15,59): error CS1061: 'qccode_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnQCGenerate_Click' and no accessible extension method 'btnQCGenerate_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'qccode_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\bugra\source\repos\QrCode\QCCode.aspx(15,59): error CS1061: 'qccode_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnQCGenerate_Click' and no accessible extension method 'btnQCGenerate_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'qccode_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\bugra\source\repos\QrCode\QCCode.aspx(18,59): error CS1061: 'qccode_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnQCRead_Click' and no accessible extension method 'btnQCRead_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'qccode_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\bugra\source\repos\QrCode\QCCode.aspx(18,59): error CS1061: 'qccode_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnQCRead_Click' and no accessible extension method 'btnQCRead_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'qccode_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your button click event either on aspx sode or code behind side. Event names should remain same on both sides. Try below aspx code. Do not change anything on code behind.

```
<form id="QCFrom" runat="server">
         <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID = "txtQCCode" runat="server">
            </asp:TextBox >
             <asp:Button ID = "btnQCGenerate" runat="server"
               Text="Create My QR Code"
               OnClick="btnGenerate_Click" />
            <hr/>
            <asp:Image ID = "imgageQRCode" Width="100px"
               Height="100px" runat="server"
               Visible="false" /> <br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID = "btnQCRead" Text="Read My QR Code"
               runat="server" OnClick="btnRead_Click" />
               <br /><br />
            <asp:Label ID = "lblQRCode" runat="server">
            </asp:Label>
         </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply it worked on my code i am no longer crashing on local host page!

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, the name of the button is `btnQCRead`, however your method to handle the click event is named `btnRead_Click`. The `AutoEventWireup` is looking for `btnQCRead_Click`, which won't match your method `btnRead_Click`. The same is true for `btnQCGenerate` and the unmatched method `btnGenerate_Click` which will need to be similarly renamed `btnQCGenerate_Click`.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes i always forgot these kind of method names and most of the times my code is looking like a big chaos, and also your solution worked, i appreciate!